# Is this Landscaping Caulk on Outdoor Retaining wall Steps

Tags: stairs, mortar, caulk

I have steps leading up through my retaining wall and a few of the stones that cap the steps have come loose.

Looking at the place where the steps were, there appears to be some kind of caulk-like material on the stone cap and the base where it sat

[image: Base][image: StoneCap]

---

**Question**

Is this some kind of landscaping caulk? Would [this product](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Loctite-PL-500-10-fl-oz-VOC-Landscape-Block-Adhesive-1683231/203266767) be an example of this kind of caulk?

**Extra Questions:**

If this some kind of caulk, should I continue to use it? Will it last for several years? Or would it be better to buy some kind of Mortar (type n?) and use that to keep the stone steps in place?

Do you think there's enough surface area (the stone base, not the backfill of stone gravel) to adhere to that my steps should be ok?

---

Thanks in advance for any answers / insights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this some kind of landscaping caulk?

**No**, that is an adhesive (glue) of an unknown type. It looks like regular construction adhesive to me.

> Would this product be an example of this...?

**Yes**

> should I... use it? Will it last for several years? ...would it be better to buy some kind of Mortar and use that to keep the stone steps in place? Do you think there's enough surface area to adhere to...?

I feel that the reason for the failure was poor original application. Also, since the original adhesive type is unknown, that also may have contributed if it was not a glue for exterior use.

Use the glue in your link but use *way more of it than was used for the original bond*, and try to scrape off all the old glue and clean all the mating surfaces first.

Answer (score 1):

It's landscape adhesive. The link you provided is an example.

Caulk is used to fill in joints or cracks between spaces to prevent water, dust, etc. from entering the crack. Usually around windows, doors, tubs and the like.

What you are looking at is an adhesive designed to hold things together. In this case to hold the step tread to the riser/retaining wall.

There is enough surface area on the block to hold the step.
Landscape adhesive will do what you want.
My experience has been that if I do a good job of gluing the block it will stay for years. I've had a few blocks come loose over time - I just clean them up, re-glue and usually have no more issues.

Clean as much of the old adhesive off the riser and the tread as possible to get a good fit. Follow the instructions on the adhesive and you should be fine.